# Location of the built python module

Tags: python, caffe

Hey people I built caffe module for nvidia jetson tx2 succesfully. But when I `import caffe` python throws  `no module named caffe` error. I have `libcaffe.a`  `libcaffe.so`  `libcaffe.so.1.0.0` under the build directory. Where should I copy these files to make sure that python is able to import module.

Comment: You installed pycaffe? You need `pycaffe` to import the caffe in python the .a and .so files are not enough.

Comment: okay then after the compilation. i entered the command sudo make pycaffe. what else i need to do more @KárolySzabó

Comment: @BerkantAy, please remove "cheers", we don't need redundant salutations. [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: @BerkantAy if you not do it yet, add the `caffe/python/caffe` dir into your `PYTHONPATH`. With something like `export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/<your/path/to/py/caffe` or check this out if some of the solution from here can help you https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/263

Answer (score 1):

When I have compiled from source, after running "cmake" I had to:

- cd into "python" folder (you shloud see the folder in the path you ran the "cmake") and run `"pip install -e ."`
- or, you will need to run `make install`.

Comment: I compile caffe library with make, where should I run ```pip install -e```

Comment: 1) please provide a screenshot of the folder you ran the "make" from 2) please try to run "make install" inside the folder you ran the "make" command